# Mounting USB disks automatically

Tags: usb, lubuntu, automount, pcmanfm

I run Lubuntu 14.04 (without a display manager). When I connect a USB disk it is not automatically mounted and it doesn't show up in the file manager PCManFM. What daemon do I need to run to enable automatic mounting of USB disks?

Comment: I use `sleep 5s && udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1` in my autostart where `sdb1` is my USB disk.

Comment: @DK Bose Thanks for the tip but in my case I want to have USB storage automatically mounted *when it's connected to the computer*

Comment: Did you look under Edit, Preferences, Volume Management? There, have you ticked "Mount removable media automatically when they are mounted"?

Comment: Yes, it's ticked (all options in PCManFM are at the default settings). If I run Lubuntu with the display manager (LightDM) removable media is mounted in PCManFM, so there must be some service/daemon started by LightDM that enables the automatic mounting.

Comment: If I start my window manager (or just PCManFM) with `dbus-launch` the icons for removable media show up in PCManFM. However, when I try to access/mount such a disk I get the error message "Not authorized to perform operation." Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two steps are required:

1. Start the window manager with `dbus-launch` in `~/.xinitrc`:

   ```
   exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session <your-wm>
   ```

   This makes the disks show up in PCManFM.
2. Add a file named (e.g.) `udisks.pkla` to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` with the content:

   ```
   [Allow mounting removable media]
   Identity=unix-group:plugdev
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
   ResultActive=yes
   ResultInactive=yes
   ResultAny=yes
   ```

Though this also allows unmounting of removable media I still get a (false) error message from PCManFM saying "Not authorized to perform operation".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to August's answer, the following. When rightclicking on the mounted removable media in pcmanfm serveral actions to choose from show up. Two of those are Umount Volume and Eject Removable media. When Unmount Volume is chosen the volume will be unmounted without warning. If on the other hand Eject Removable media is chosen, the volume will be unmounted but not ejected and a "Not authorized to perform operation" message will appear. For permission to eject the media, another rule has to be added to `/etc/polkit-1/localautority/50-local.d`. In this directory create a file called udisks.drive-eject.pkla and add the following code to it:

`[Allow ejecting removable media]
 Identity=unix-group:plugdev
 Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media
 ResultActive=yes
 ResultInactive=yes
 ResultAny=yes`

Now the removable media is ejectable. There will be no more warnings. Leftclicking on the mounted removable media in pcmanfm tells pcmanfm to eject the media, hence the warning before adding the second rule.